# Отключить редактирование jTable

Tags: java, swing

Как отключить редактирование значений ячеек, но оставить возможность выделять строку в jTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании таблицы, Вы можете определить метод редактирования `isCellEditable` он в отличии от `setEnabled()` и `setFocusable()` сохранит возможность выделения ячейки.

```
    TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```